# Enable post method in codeignitor {if i try GET method its goto action page but not redirected}

Tags: codeigniter

i am trying to send some value on next page via POST method i try on empty place its working but when i try in codeignitor system its redirect on same page how to solve

page 1

```
<form action="http://localhost/v/ol" method="GET">

<input type="text" name="file" value="">

<input type="submit">
<br>
```

page 2

```
 <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

 <div class="container m-b-30">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 page-breadcrumb">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                        <a href="<?php echo lang_base_url(); ?>"><?php                      echo trans("breadcrumb_home"); ?></a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active"><?php echo  html_escape($page->title); ?></li>
                </ol><h1 class="page-title"><?php echo html_escape($page->title); ?></h1>
            </div>
            <?php 
         if(isset($_GET['file']))
        {
        $file=$_GET['file'];
            $url = 'https://openload.co/f/';
            header( "refresh:10;url=$url$file" );}
            ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">

    (function () {
   var timeLeft = 10,
    cinterval;

   var timeDec = function (){
    timeLeft--;
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = timeLeft;
    if(timeLeft === 0){
        clearInterval(cinterval);
    }
};

cinterval = setInterval(timeDec, 1000);
})();

</script>

 <div align="center"><h1>You will Redirected in <span id="countdown">10</span> Seconds</h1></div></div></div>
```

when i try to post method its not go action page but in get method its goto action page but its not redirected to target link   $url$file

Answer (score 1):

add enctype='multipart/form-data' in form tag.